# DRY this Rails/Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

How could i DRY (don't repeat yourself)/factorize the following code. I feel i can do it but as I'm really a newbie, I don't manage to do it.

/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
 protected


    def configure_permitted_parameters

      if params[:controller] == "user"     
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
          u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
          u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
      else # for clients access 
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |c|
          c.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |c|
          c.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
      end

    end
```

Comment: Remove if/else I see no diff inside the 2 conditionals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@DanielKnippers gave a good answer, but you could further DRY your code like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  [:sign_up, :account_update].each do |sanitize_me|
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(sanitize_me) do |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right, my answer could have been further DRY'd :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Well, since your methods for `:sign_up` and `:account_update` are entirely *equivalent* in the `"user"` case and the `else` case, I have no idea why you divided it like that. The only difference is you give the block variable a different *name* in each case, (`u` and `c`), but that does not alter the behavior.

Thus:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

See @UriAgassi's answer for a further reduced definition of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with everyone else about the conditional (don't see what it's for) and so I came up with this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  actions = [:sign_up, :account_update]
  actions.each{|action| sanitize_devise_param_for(action) }
end
def sanitize_devise_param_for(action, permitted = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(action) do |c|
    c.permit(permitted)
  end
end
```

Mostly just break things down into their own methods. I find writing DRY code is much easier, and natural, to write when I'm doing a good job of enforcing single responsibility well.